# How to pass a query string with ASP.NET hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to pass an ID as a query string to another page.  this is the hyper link code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='../request/inforequest.aspx?ID=     + <%# Eval(ID) %>' Target='_BLANK' Text='Request a Showing' alt='Request a Showing' border='0'
                                CssClass="btn btn-primary"></asp:HyperLink>
```

This is the resulting url:

```
http://localhost:51378/request/inforequest.aspx?ID=%20+%20<%# Eval(ID) %>
```

It is passing the id, 20 is the correct value in this case but it only adds it where there are spaces, I dont understand what is happening here can someone please help?

Comment: it's not passing the id 20, it's passing %20 which is a encoded space character...

Comment: why there is a `+` at the beginning?

Comment: i guess its not working at all then, i am new to asp forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work correctly

```
<asp:hyperlink runat="server" navigateurl='<%# string.Concat("../request/inforequest.aspx?ID=", Eval("ID"))%>' target="_blank" Text="Click Here" />
```

Source

http://forums.asp.net/t/973441.aspx?How+to+Concat+String+in+aspx+page

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='~/request/inforequest.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ID") %>' target="_blank" 
    Text="Request a Showing" alt="Request a Showing" border="0"
    CssClass="btn btn-primary">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: same thing as above, it just passes <%# Eval(ID) %> to the url.  I've tried all manner of combinations of quotes and i either get a This tag is not well formed error or it just wont evaluate the Eval

Comment: What specific error did you get with this version, and what link was generated in the output?

Comment: this was the URL localhost:51378/request/inforequest.aspx?ID=<%# Eval(ID) %>

Comment: i add double quotes around ID in the Eval and the syntax highlighting seemed to recognize it but then i get a parser error The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: The reason you got the error is because you can't have two sets of similar quote types for a single attribute value.